# Android Wear - is Google Maps API v2 available?

Tags: java, android, google-maps, wear-os

I'm trying to display a Google map (Google Maps API V2 for Android) on my Sony SmartWatch3.

In my wear layout, i'm using a MapFragment with this code :

```
<fragment
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/mapFragment"
class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"/>
```

My wear main activity implements OnMapReadyCallback :

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {
SupportMapFragment fragment = ( SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.mapFragment);
// Getting Google Map
GoogleMap googleMap = fragment.getMap();
```

When I compile the program with Google Play Services for wearable in the classpath, it doesn't compile.

When I compile the program with full Google Play Services in the classpath, it compiles successfully but when I execute the program on the smartwatch, I get this exception:

```
02-03 16:44:23.456 2377-2377/com.example.andy.myfirstwearablemapapplication E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.andy.myfirstwearablemapapplication, PID: 2377
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class fragment
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:763)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
at android.support.wearable.view.WatchViewStub.inflate(WatchViewStub.java:179)
at android.support.wearable.view.WatchViewStub.onApplyWindowInsets(WatchViewStub.java:148)
at android.view.View.dispatchApplyWindowInsets(View.java:6514)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchApplyWindowInsets(ViewGroup.java:5782)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchApplyWindowInsets(ViewGroup.java:5786)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchApplyWindowInsets(ViewGroup.java:5786)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchApplyWindowInsets(PhoneWindow.java:2335)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.dispatchApplyInsets(ViewRootImpl.java:1205)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1423)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1054)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5779)
at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:767)
at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:580)
at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:550)
at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:753)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to find dynamic class com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.CreatorImpl
at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.x.a(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.x.U(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.x.S(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapsInitializer.initialize(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment$b.nO(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment$b.a(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.a.a(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.a.onInflate(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment.onInflate(Unknown Source)
at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManager.java:2115)
at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:5282)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:733)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
at android.support.wearable.view.WatchViewStub.inflate(WatchViewStub.java:179)
at android.support.wearable.view.WatchViewStub.onApplyWindowInsets(WatchViewStub.java:148)
at android.view.View.dispatchApplyWindowInsets(View.java:6514)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchApplyWindowInsets(ViewGroup.java:5782)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchApplyWindowInsets(ViewGroup.java:5786)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchApplyWindowInsets(ViewGroup.java:5786)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchApplyWindowInsets(PhoneWindow.java:2335)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.dispatchApplyInsets(ViewRootImpl.java:1205)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1423)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1054)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5779)
at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:767)
at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:580)
at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:550)
at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:753)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

Is it really possible to display a map with Google Maps API V2 for Android on an Android Wear watch ?

If yes, can you tell me how ? :)

If it is not possible, is there any other solution to display a map (if possible, a draggable / zoomable map)?

Thanks in advance :)

Best regards.

Comment: Hello.

The latest version of Google Play Services (7.3) on the Play Store indicates in "What's new" : "Maps API v2 for Android Wear".

However, it still doesn't seem to work.

Can we expect an update of Android Wear to support this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, Android wear can not display Google map right now.

There is work in progress for doing maps on wear.--From a googler

Comment: Hello.

The latest version of Google Play Services (7.3) on the Play Store indicates in "What's new" : "Maps API v2 for Android Wear".

However, it still doesn't seem to work.

Can we expect an update of Android Wear to support this?

Thank you.